# Magento2 - Is it possible to get specific store url in cms block?

Tags: url, magento-2.2.5, stores

I am trying to get store URL or base URL for a specific store in cms block.

I have tried `{{store _store="1"}}`

Also, `{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}`

I wanted to know if this is going to work or is there any solution for this

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Comment: Is there a solution for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

```
<a href="{{store url=""}}">Link to Base URL</a>
```

or This may be helpful

```
<a href="{{store direct_url=""}}">Link to Base URL</a>
```

Comment: I have tried both the solution but i am not able to get store1 url in store2

Answer (score 0):

You can use base url followed by store code `{{base url=''}}storecode`

or

```
{{base url='storecode'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me:

```
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url/storecode"}}why-ABC">Why ABC</a>
```